# sequence List of disjunction with tuples

Tags: scala, scalaz

I use `sequenceU` to turn inside type out while working with disjunctions in scalaz.

for e.g.

`val res = List[\/[Errs,MyType]]` 
doing

`res.sequenceU` will give `\/[Errs,List[MyType]]`

Now if I have a `val res2 = List[(\/[Errs,MyType], DefModel)]` - `List` containing tuples of disjunctions; what's the right way to convert

`res2` to `\/[Errs,List[ (Mype,DefModel)]`

Comment: Would `res2.map { case (d, m) => d.map((_, m)) }.sequenceU` work?

Comment: Which could be simplified by using `traverseU { ... }` instead of `map { ... }.sequenceU`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the most straightforward way to write this is probably just with a `traverse` and `map`:

```
def sequence(xs: List[(\/[Errs, MyType], DefModel)]): \/[Errs, List[(MyType, DefModel)]] =
  xs.traverseU { case (m, d) => m.map((_, d)) }
```

It's worth noting, though, that tuples are themselves traversable, so the following is equivalent:

```
def sequence(xs: List[(\/[Errs, MyType], DefModel)]): \/[Errs, List[(MyType, DefModel)]] =
  xs.traverseU(_.swap.sequenceU.map(_.swap))
```

Note that this would be even simpler if the disjunction were on the right side of the tuple. If you're willing to make that change, you can also more conveniently take advantage of the fact that `Traverse` instances compose:

```
def sequence(xs: List[(DefModel, \/[Errs, MyType])]): \/[Errs, List[(DefModel, MyType)]] =
  Traverse[List].compose[(DefModel, ?)].sequenceU(xs)
```

I'm using kind-projector here but you could also write out the type lambda.